# iFrame is loading index.html instead of local html file specified in the src

Tags: reactjs, iframe, react-router

I have a React project which consists of many pages.

One page contains an iframe that must load a local HTML file. Instead of that, it loads index.html file (homepage).

I am using "react-router-dom" for route and links.

I think the problem is with redirecting the link of the HTML file to the homepage file.

If this is the problem, how I can disable redirecting to the homepage when calling the desired HTML file?

**Edit:**

The HTML file is a part of a third-party SDK bundle and can't be converted to a react component.

Comment: Please add relevant code in your question.

Comment: Please edit your question to actually include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). People may be more willing and/or capable of helping you if there's code to see and diagnose/debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the file is a third party library**

Consider putting it in the public directory and using PUBLIC_URL to access the file.

```
<iframe src=`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/bundle/test.htm` ... />
```

**If you need to load another component**

Load the component that renders the page directly instead of doing an iframe. That way you are not constrained to path based rules.

**If you want path based rules**

Consider adding a nested route:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Or v6 route: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#nested-routes

Prefer not to intentionally break react-router but work within its constraints.

I would recommend putting an absolute path if it was an external route; however, since it is an internal link it will still conform to react router. Or use public folder.

Comment: The iframe is used to load a third-party SDK bundle (the desired HTML file and a lot of js and CSS files). I can't convert this HTML to a component because I need to leave it as a bundle folder in case I want to update it.

Comment: try using the public folder, https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder

Answer (score 1):

See in react app you can only route components.
For example, in the app.js of your react application you do

> **App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, } from 'react-router-dom'
function App(){
   return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
           <Route exact path='/' element={<Your_component />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
   )
 }
```

> The Problem

**In the react you can route through the components **according to me**. If you try to route another file by writing the **URL = 'localhost:3000/another-html-file.html'**. It tries to find the URL inside the app.js routes but it is unable to find it and you see it can't find it hence, it always returns the homepage so you only can see the index.html(homepage).**

> The solution

**If you want to route in another HTML file.
1 - Try to build it as a component so it will be easy for the react app to route in it.
2 - Try to set up another route system only for HTML files which might be difficult because your react app always works from the src file containing all the files as JS extensions.**
I prefer the first one.
Hope it might help.

Comment: Regarding the first solution, I am not able to build a component from that HTML page because it is a third-party SDK bundle.